# How to check NOT NULL when calling RFC_READ_TABLE?

Tags: python, sap-erp, saprfc, pyrfc

I am trying to get data by using python connect SAP system. Here I have question about how to filter one specific field IS NOT EMPTY?

For example below, how to filter the field QNAME is not empty. In SAP, we can easily set.
Thanks a lot!

```
table = 'LTAP'
options = [{ 'TEXT': "LGNUM = '586'" and "VLTYP = 'GPA'" and "NLTYP = 'PD2'"}]
fields = ['TANUM','VLTYP','VLPLA','NLTYP','NLPLA','QDATU','QNAME']
pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
rowskips = 0

print("----Begin of Batch---")
result = conn.call("RFC_READ_TABLE",
QUERY_TABLE = table, 
DELIMITER='|',
FIELDS = fields,\
OPTIONS = options,
ROWSKIPS = rowskips, 
ROWCOUNT = 50 )
pp.pprint(result['DATA'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In ABAP SQL (A.K.A. Open SQL), "not equal" corresponds to the operator `<>`. With pyrfc, it will be:

```
options = [{ 'TEXT': "QNAME <> '' and LGNUM = '586' and VLTYP = 'GPA' and NLTYP = 'PD2'"},
{ 'TEXT': " and QDATU = '20160422'" }]
```

Note that there are two lines because `TEXT` is only 72 characters in `RFC_READ_TABLE`. If you have more than 72 characters, split the condition into several lines, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504963/usage-of-subqueries-in-rfc-read-table-options), i.e. `RFC_READ_TABLE` will pad each line with spaces to obtain exactly 72 characters, and will collate all the lines without any transformation to form the WHERE clause.

Comment: THANK YOU! Do you know how to get and filter the current date field QDATU? (get the yesterday's date.) Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: In databases connected to ABAP-based systems, date fields correspond to a YYYYMMDD CHAR format, and it's always expressed according to Gregorian calendar. So, yesterday, June 17th, 2021, corresponds to the text `20210617`.

Comment: You mean like this?: options = [{ 'TEXT': "QNAME <> '' and LGNUM = '586' and VLTYP = 'GPA' and NLTYP = 'PD2' and QDATU = '20160422'"}]

Comment: thank you! I tried to add the option QDATU = '20160422', and then I got error msg. did you mean that after each condition, there should be a new line to split them? like this? options = [{ 'TEXT': "QNAME <> '' and 
          /*new line*/  LGNUM = '586' and  /*new line*/ VLTYP = 'GPA' and....

Comment: I completed my answer, I hope it will clarify.